# Link with a "functions library" shader

Tags: shader, webgl

I have multiple shaders in a webgl app that all use a few common functions.
These common functions are pretty long and take a few seconds to compile.
Is it possible to create a sort of "library" shader and link to it from several programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to precompile functions.

You can use string manipulation to insert the functions into the GLSL but it is not possible to precompile the functions or compile them separately.

It may be possible to compile your shaders asynchronously. This won't make them compile any faster but it will at least not freeze the browser. See: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/KHR_parallel_shader_compile/

Comment: With this atleast I can give some feedback to the user that something is going on and to unstuck the UI. Thank you!